# How do I authenticate to SharePoint in Bot Framework using logged in user?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm working on a bot running on MS Teams.

I'm trying to get logged in user information and use it to authenticate to SharePoint API, but without luck so far.

I'm using the controller from the following example:
https://github.com/stephaneey/transparent-auth-bot/blob/master/transparent-auth-bot/Controllers/MessagesController.cs#L64

But I'm unable to get the token (line 64), it remains null/

Answer (score 3):

The sample you are providing is demonstating the ability to get a Graph API token and reuse it in a Bot.

As you can see [here](https://github.com/stephaneey/transparent-auth-bot/blob/master/transparent-auth-bot/Controllers/WebChatController.cs#L37), this token is generated during a specific authentication process: there is a website displaying a webchat, and when you want to access it you have to login. That's where the value of the `"GraphAccessToken"` is generated and stored in a BotData object, which can be accessed from the code of the bot.

Here if you use MS Teams you never asked the user to login, so there is no magic: the value will be null.

In a few words, if your target channel is Teams, you will not be able to automatically get an user token which you can use to query SharePoint API: you have to go through a manual login process.